# How to validate POST data in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

I am testing an API in Laravel 5.4. I am now in the part of storing a record via  API. I am having some issues on how to use Request::input() or Input::get() to validate POST data.

LessonsController.php

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Lesson;
    use App\Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer;
    //use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LessonsController extends ApiController
{

    /**
     * @var Acme\Transformers\LessonTransformer
     */
    protected $lessonTransformer;

    function __construct(LessonTransformer $lessonTransformer)
    {
        $this->lessonTransformer = $lessonTransformer;
       // $this->middleware('sentry.auth')->only('post'); // basic level of protection for creating a lession
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     * If we are using basic authentication, we should be using SSL
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store()
    {

        if( ! Input::get('title') || ! Input::get('body')){
            return $this->setStatusCode(422)->respondWithError('Parameters failed validation for a lesson.');
        }

        Lesson::create($request->all());

        return $this->respondCreated('Lesson successfully created.');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $lesson = Lesson::find($id);

        if( ! $lesson) {

            return $this->respondNotFound('Lesson does not exist');


        }

        return $this->respond([

            'data' => $this->lessonTransformer->transform($lesson)

        ]);

    }

}
```

When I test my code above with POSTMAN using POST request. I am prompted with "**{"error":"Parameters failed validation for a lesson.","status_code":422}**"
.
I receive an error when I try to add data or I don't add data.

Do you have any idea how to correct my store() code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please specify the route for this method and also your request url you are sending through POSTMAN.

Comment: The route and request url for the store method is the same: http://test.app:8000/api/v1/lessons.

The request is POST.

Comment: lets assume your route is pointing correctly to your method. Before doing any hard stuff, first off just return "Hello world.."; at the top of your store method to see if the request is getting there.  Even if you get past the validation part, you are trying to access params with $request var which is not available to your method. you can make it accessible with (Request $request) in your input parameters..

Comment: Are you using your postman correctly ? You have to put your inputs *text* & *body* as **Body** and don't forget to select *x-www-form-urlencoded* If this didn't helped. please provide a screenshot of postman

Comment: This code seems to work (there's a correct "validation" failed response) . The issue is probably to do with the actual input you're passing. Do a `dd(Input::all())` to see what it is.

Comment: yes of'course. didn't think of that.

Comment: @apokryfos you were right all along! can you post your comment above as answer please? your trick worked like a charm

Comment: @redshot I only suggested a way to debug the input. You should provide an answer to the question stating what the problem was and what you did to fix it (since you're the one that fixed it in the end).

Comment: @apokryfos I have now posted the correct answer with note. thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my code above is that it does not have the $request var in the store() method.

In my code be below, the Request class is now injected into store method.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    if (! $request->input('title') or ! $request->input('body') )   
    {
         return $this->respondUnprocessableEntity('Parameters failed validation for a lesson.');
    }

    Lesson::create($request->all());

    return $this->respondCreated('Lesson successfully created.');

}
```

Note: In postman, select x-www-form-urlencoded in **Body**

Answer (score 2):

To validate form data in Laravel simply use "[Laravel Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation)". This allows you to validate your form data in request using some predefined validation rules of Laravel and if you need you can also create you custom laravel validation logic.

According to Laravel docs:

> Form requests are custom request classes that contain validation logic.

It will simplify your validation logic, make your code neat and let you handle complex validations.

Comment: At the moment, I am not using any form. I just storing data via the API with POSTman

Comment: @redshot It is not necessary to use it with only forms you can use it to validate any type of request. You just have to type hint into your store function.

Comment: thanks your answer is close to what i need. but i think Request $request is enought for now

Answer (score 1):

Try this, might help

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
    if( ! $request->has('title') || ! $request->has('body')){
        return $this->setStatusCode(422)->respondWithError('Parameters failed validation for a lesson.');
    }

    Lesson::create($request->all());

    return $this->respondCreated('Lesson successfully created.');

    }
```